# Push array inside async function in javascript produces empty or nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, promise, push

I have an async function to store several files from a form into Firebase Storage and i want to collect file names so that i can store them in the database in the next step.

The problem is that the array with file names that is generated is sort of "nested" and when stored into database - the field is empty. When i return array in the console (please see picture below), array is:

1. Empty if pasted with JSON stringify (green line in the picture)
2. Is a "multi level" array of a sort which can not be saved to database (at list as array) (pink line in the picture)
3. Array is empty when converted to String (blue line in the picture)

Please suggest how to correct this. Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
var $dbTimestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now();
var $fileNames = [];

// I use Promise to wait for all names to be pushed to Array
let myPromise = new Promise(function(success){
    success(
        // Function triggers Async function for each file to be uploaded
        $filesForUpload.map(async function(file, index){
            var $fileName = "rfp/rfp" + $dbTimestamp.valueOf().slice(0,12) + (index + 1);
            // Waiting for the upload to complete
            await $storageRef.child($fileName).put(file).then(function(snapshot){
                console.log("200 File upload completed. File(s) " + (index + 1) + "/" + $filesForUpload.length);
                // Here is where I update my array
                $fileNames.push($fileName);
            }).catch(function(error){
                console.error("500 File upload failed. File(s) " + (index + 1) + "/" + $filesForUpload.length, error);
                NotifyServerError();
            });
        })
    );
});
// Once promise is completed, i try to pass list of file names to next function.
myPromise.then(
    function(success){
        UpdateDB($fileNames, $dbTimestamp);
        console.log(JSON.stringify($fileNames));
        console.log($fileNames);
        console.log($fileNames.toString());
    }
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can't `await` inside methods like `.map()`, `.forEach()`, `.filter()` etc. but you can in a `for(... of ...)` loop.
- Using `.map()` is useless here, because it's not returning anything.
- You're mixing `await`-style and `.then()`-Promise-style, here's the `await` style only.

```js
const $dbTimestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now();
const $fileNames = [];

const myPromise = async() => {
  for (let file of $filesForUpload) {
    const $fileName = "rfp/rfp" + $dbTimestamp.valueOf().slice(0, 12) + (index + 1);
    try {
      const snapshot = await $storageRef.child($fileName).put(file);
      console.log("200 File upload completed. File(s) " + (index + 1) + "/" + $filesForUpload.length);
      // Here is where I update my array
      $fileNames.push($fileName);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("500 File upload failed. File(s) " + (index + 1) + "/" + $filesForUpload.length, error);
      NotifyServerError();
    }
  }
}

( async () => {
  await myPromise();
  UpdateDB($fileNames, $dbTimestamp); // <- You probably want to await this as well...
  console.log(JSON.stringify($fileNames));
  console.log($fileNames);
  console.log($fileNames.toString());
})()
```

Comment: Hello Jeremy, thank you very much for your response. I understood the first part, but why do we need to have a 2nd async to execute code once promise is fulfilled? Can't `MyPromise.then()` be used instead?

Comment: You're welcome! `MyPromise.then()` is the "old" Promise-style, I never use it because it's a guaranteed headache and an easy callback hell. `await myPromise();` is so much cleaner, easier to read and to maintain. But yeah, you can use `myPromise.then()` if you like

Comment: You can easily chain `await myPromise(); await updateDB(); await myPromise2(); await myPromise3()` but if you want to use `myPromise.then( updateDB.then( myPromise2.then( myPromise3.then( ... )))))` it's up to you :)

Comment: I have tested and code works! Thanks again. I have spent about 12 hours on this today, with no luck. One more question please, my old code produced nested array of some sort because I used `map` in the code?

Comment: PS: I had to update the "index" part when assigning file name.

Comment: I'm not sure because I don't know the output of your old code